# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Text to Speech API for my Android Application.

**I followed:-**

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries this quick start guide for this.

To set credentials guide says to use windows powershell command prompt. Even though I tried it as it stated. it never works in Android.

But whenever I run my project it crashes with :

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
>   environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined
>   pointing to a file defining the credentials

Documentation is not detailed about Android devices.

So, Am I missing a point? How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for Android devices?

Comment: I answered a very similar question this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310714/using-google-speech-cloud-api-from-android-give-error-in-google-application-cred/60313773#60313773

Comment: yes the answer make sense. But I am trying to this project just for my own. I will use TextToSpeech , will download files programmatically and going to put them to my server.

Comment: It is the same issue. The java client library is not meant for use on Android, just backend and desktop systems. Your Android app should route the request through some backend.